# Perl Editor helper features - go to declaration / go to implementations

Tags: perl, intellij-idea, ide, editor, helper

I want to refactor some local `Perl packages` that I wrote poorly, but I have calls to their subroutines in a bunch of scripts scattered in a tree of directories.

I need an editor to allow me to jump to subroutine declaration and to find implementations/usages.

I have tried `https://github.com/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA` and `Notepad++ SourceCookiefier`.

SourceCookiefier isn't a real solution, it cannot find implementations, and you have to manually specify the files that you want it to index.

On the other hand, `Perl5-IDEA`seems to be more up to the job, but when I specify the module's root folder, it starts to index everything that it finds, until it hangs/runs out of memory. 
Besides those `.pl/.pm` scripts I have lots of other data files, which I cannot separate for the moment from those directories. I would have needed an exclude type filter for them. I cannot find an exclude filter in `IntelliJ + Perl5-IDEA plugin`.

So, do you know what editor could I use to benefit from `go to declaration / go to implementations` and capable of importing `.pl/.pm` files from subdirectories of a specified root directory?

Comment: Did you try [`ctags for vim`](https://andrew.stwrt.ca/posts/vim-ctags/) (supports Perl) and/or Perl's module [`Perl::Tags`](http://search.cpan.org/~osfameron/Perl-Tags-0.30/README.pod)?

Comment: I haven't. I'm on Windows.

Comment: I believe that all of that can be used on Windows. The use of `ctags` is a very old, traditional (and effective) method of doing what you want.  On the other hand, I'd imagine that major integrated environments have that functionality. Have you looked at [`Padre`](http://padre.perlide.org/), and how is ActiveState in this regard?

Comment: I don't know how to install Padre without the additional unwanted stuff. I already have StrawberryPerl installed, so I don't need another one. ActiveState requires its own flavour of Perl installed, as well. It would take a day just to reinstall all the CPAN modules that I need in a new Perl installation.

Comment: Thank you to whoever gave the `-1` without explaining why.

Comment: I didn't realize that Padre for Windows only comes in a big bundle. As for ActiveState, it has a separate editor, which comes in two versions, "Komodo Edit" (free) and "Komodo IDE".  The feature you need may not be in the free version (I don't know) but there is the 21-day trial for the other one.  This is a very good editor.  But again, the ctags-with-gvim and the Perl module, from my first comment, can surely help you out. I don't know what is your editor of choice, but Perl::Tags seems to not depend on that..

Answer (score 0):

How about eclipse?
You can open all your modules in separate tabs. If you want to find the next use of a soubroutine, just select it's name and press `Ctrl+K`. If you want to jump to the declatation of the subroutine in current module just select it's name and press `F3`. If it is defined in another module just `Ctrl+H` (this will search in all the project modules for the given name; tip: if you want to search for soubroutine `do_something`, search for `sub do_something`) and it will return you were in which the soubroutine is defined.
 It also indexes your soubroutines (clicking on a soubroutnie will jump you straight to your sub declaration).
To asnwwer your comment, yes you can add a filter to select only the wanted extensions.
[image]

Comment: Can I give it a folder for it to search for `.pl/.pm` files and exclude the rest from indexing?

Comment: You can go on the menu->file->open and in the windows that appears go to the wanted folder and type in the search box `*.pm|*.pl`. Then select all of them and press open.

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: Which version of Eclipse should I install? Isn't there a blank version? They all have flavours, Java, C, PHP, etc. I went for PHP and added EPIC module, but the menus are still PHP related.